# Telnet 23 gives response using command prompt, But telnet using chrome sockets gives junk characters as response

Tags: sockets, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, telnet

Below i mentioned the issue as steps

1, When I try to create a telnet Ip port 23 connection using command prompt i am getting a response that asks for login as

```
Telnet *.*.*.* 
Connecting ....
Welcome to Microsoft telnet service
```

2, When I try to establish a telnet connection to same server and port using chrome Sockets Api  through my chrome extension i am getting junk characters as

```
ÿý%ÿûÿûÿý'ÿýÿý
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original telnet protocol has a capability and options exchange at the beginning of the connection. A real telnet program hides this exchange but since you simply make a socket connection to port 23 you have to deal with it by implementing the [telnet protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854) properly.

Comment: Hi Steffen, Can you suggest me how to deal with that negotiation using chrome Sockets tcp.

Comment: @MohanRajNagarajan: There is nothing special with Chrome Sockets. You "simply" have to implement the telnet protocol which is described in [RFC854](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854).

Comment: Hi Steffen, Finally I made a negotiation and able to access Server.